# VB.NET - Error when Emedding Powerpoint Object

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

Please be gentle, I'm a newbie!

I am trying to embed a Powerpoint viewer onto a VB.NET form.  When I run the following code it throws an exception  :

```
Imports PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Handles Button1.Click

        Const PPTFile = "C:\Report.pptx"
        Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
        Dim oPPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
        oPPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application()
        oPPTPres = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(PPTFile)
    End Sub
End Class
```

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
>   ErrorCode=-2147221164   HResult=-2147221164   Message=Retrieving the
>   COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).   Source=mscorlib

Is there something wrong with the code or is the clue in the "Class not registered"? If it is, how can I tell which class?

Thanks

Comment: Try to set a param `WithWindows` to `False` in `Presentations.Open`

Comment: Is PowerPoint installed on your machine?